# How to take a fraction such as 3/4 as input?

Tags: python, python-3.x, fractions

I am running some code in which I am expecting user to insert fraction which will be computed and stored as a float value in a variable.

I am using the following command. It works fine when I give input such as `4.5`:

```
a = float(input('>> '))
```

But something like `3/4` gives me an error. I know what the problem is, I would like to know if there is an alternative way to input a fraction which gets solved and stored as a float in a variable.

Comment: `'3/4'` isn't the representation of a floating point number. If you are allowing the user to enter fractions, you will need to parse them yourself.

Comment: read the input as a string then apply the solution described in the answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2371436/evaluating-a-mathematical-expression-in-a-string

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/fractions.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As noted by Josh Lee, wrap it in a `Fraction` (`from fractions import Fraction`) and then cast it to `float`:

```
r = float(Fraction(input(">>> ")))
```

this accept floats and strings that have a form of:

```
[sign] numerator ['/' denominator]
```

[as noted in its docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fractions.html#fractions.Fraction).

You should of course wrap it in a `try-except` to guard against unexpected input that doesn't abide to that form.

Comment: It may be worth _not_ converting the resulting Fraction to float if the application can deal with that, as a Fraction doesn't lose precision and stays maximally precise as long as the operations done on it leave it as a Fraction.